# Unset certain items from session array when they're clicked?

Tags: php, html, arrays, session, unset

What I'm basically looking for is the ability to remove a certain item from the array when that item is clicked, for this instance... If I hit "Two", it will disappear.

Demo: http://query.notesquare.me

**CODE:**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="input-create-playlist" placeholder="Playlist Name" name="create_playlist" />
    <input type="submit" id="button-create-playlist" value="Create Playlist" />
</form>

<?php
    ini_set("session.save_path", "/home/kucerajacob/public_html/query.notesquare.me/test-sessions");
    session_start();

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $create_playlist = $_POST['create_playlist'];

        $_SESSION['user_playlists'][] = $create_playlist;
    }

    $playlists = array("One", "Two", "Three");

    if (isset($_SESSION['user_playlists'])) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['user_playlists']); $i++) {
            array_unshift($playlists, $_SESSION['user_playlists'][$i]);
        }
    }

    $_SESSION['main'] = $playlists;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($playlists); $i++) {
        echo $playlists[$i] . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible, you'll need to handle that request as well. If you want the `click` posted, a simple `<button>` next to that should suffice.

Upon rendering the markup, (of course using the session array) use the key which can be used in unsetting the values.

```
<?php

// initialization
if(empty($_SESSION['user_playlists'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_playlists'] = array("One", "Two", "Three");
}

if(isset($_POST['add'], $_POST['create_playlist'])) {
    // handle additions
    $_SESSION['user_playlists'][] = $_POST['create_playlist'];
}

if(isset($_POST['remove'])) {
    // handle remove
    $key = $_POST['remove'];
    unset($_SESSION['user_playlists'][$key]);
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="input-create-playlist" placeholder="Playlist Name" name="create_playlist" />
    <input type="submit" id="button-create-playlist" name="add" value="Create Playlist" />
    <hr/>
    <?php foreach($_SESSION['user_playlists'] as $k => $p): ?>
        <?php echo $p; ?>&nbsp;<button type="submit" name="remove" value="<?php echo $k; ?>">Remove</button><br/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

[Sample Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LINzZR)

Comment: Thanks man! You solved some hidden inner issues I was having as well! <3

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($playlists); $i++) {
       // echo $playlists[$i] . "<br />";
  printf('<a href="php_pagename.php?query=%1$s">%1$s</a><br/>', $playlists[$i]);
}

if ($_GET['query'])
{
unset($playlists['query']);
}
```